# Oval ProgressBar TIGHTLY ENCAPSULATING text

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

Before marking it as duplicate please read it fully. This is not about creating another progress bar with text in android. I want the progress bar size to be dynamic to cover the text size. The other solutions put a small text in the middle of a huge progressbar. This should slightly cover it.

I'm trying to create oval progressbar with a textview in the center. I want the whole progressbar to encapsulate the text. So it's width and height shouldn't be constant. Instead, it should be slightly larger than the textview. I tried to encapsulate progressbar and the textview (width/height:wrap_content) in a relative layout. I tried aligning left/right/bottom/top of progressbar with textview with textview plus some negative padding but I crops the oval progressbar. Here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar0"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txtCategoryTitle"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/txtCategoryTitle"
    android:paddingLeft="-50dp"
    android:paddingRight="-50dp"

    android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtCategoryTitle"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txtCategoryTitle"
    android:paddingTop="-50dp"
    android:paddingBottom="-50dp"

    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="65"
    android:layout_below="@id/clickBtn"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >

</ProgressBar>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCategoryTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="MY CUSTOM TEXT"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:elevation="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, I'm open to suggestions for better/easier ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,
It was a silly approach. Here is the new code for future reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCategoryTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"

        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="MY CUSTOM TEXT"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txtCategoryTitle"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/txtCategoryTitle"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtCategoryTitle"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txtCategoryTitle"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar0"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="65"
        >

    </ProgressBar>





</RelativeLayout>
```